# How to enable git protocol in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I would like to do git archive or git clone using git protocol not ssh or https. How can I do that with bitbucket?

Comment: Hosted or cloud?

Comment: You cannot: git protocol is not supported.

Comment: indeed not supported  https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11899/not-able-to-use-git-protocol-url